# Twillio accountsid and token issues

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am having trouble getting my token and account sid to work. i set them as constants in the file and the following error appears

Error:
throw 'Client requires an Account SID and Auth Token set explicitly ' +
            ^
Client requires an Account SID and Auth Token set explicitly or via the TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID and TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN environment variables

```js
const sid = xxxxxxxxxxx'
const tkn = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'

function Client(sid, tkn, host, api_version, timeout) {
    //Required client config

    if (!sid || !tkn) {
        if (process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID && process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN) {
            this.accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
            this.authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
        }
        else {
            throw 'Client requires an Account SID and Auth Token set explicitly ' +
                'or via the TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID and TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN environment variables';
        }
    }
    else {
        //if auth token/SID passed in manually, trim spaces
        this.accountSid = sid.replace(/ /g, '');
        this.authToken = tkn.replace(/ /g, '');
    }

    //Optional client config
    this.host = host || defaultHost;
    this.apiVersion = api_version || defaultApiVersion;
    this.timeout = timeout || 31000; // request timeout in milliseconds
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are setting `sid` and `tkn` as constants outside the `Client` function, however you also name the first two arguments passed into the function as `sid` and `tkn`. Within the scope of `Client` that means that `sid` and `tkn` are whatever you pass as arguments to the function.

My guess is that you are calling the `Client` function without any arguments and that leads to this error.

Rather than setting the `sid` and `tkn` in the file with the `Client` function, I recommend you pass them in as arguments when you call it.

```
const client = new Client(sid, tkn);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.